# How to add background image in a textbox using jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I have a textbox I want to change the watermark on focus.

Please correct me:

```
$('body').ready(function() {
    $('#edit-submitted-full-name').focus(function() {
        $(this).css({background:'#FFFFFF'});
    });

    $('#edit-submitted-full-name').blur(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            $(this).css({background:'url("images/text_fullname.png") no-repeat scroll 7px 5px #FFFFFF'});
        };
    });
});
```

Comment: try with .css("background-image", "url(images/text_fullname.png)");  and also set other attributes like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can probably do this more cleanly using a css class and avoid having to handle the path to your images. If you added a new css class called "hintable" to everything you wanted to have or not have a hint it would be doubly better.

HTMl

```
<input type="text" id="edit-submitted-full-name" name="edit-submitted-full-name" class="hintable" value="" />
```

CSS:

```
#edit-submitted-full-name.hint 
{
    url(../images/text_fullname.png) no-repeat scroll 7px 5px #FFFFFF; 
}

#some-other-input.hint 
{
    url(../images/text_someother.png) no-repeat scroll 7px 5px #FFFFFF; 
}
```

and then your code would look like:

```
$(function(){
    $(".hintable").each(function(){
        ToggleHint($(this)); // add class on page load to elements with "hintable" class
    });        

    $(".hintable").focus(function(){
        $(this).removeClass("hint"); // handle all focus hints
    });

    $(".hintable").blur(function(){
        ToggleHint(this); // handle all blur hints
    });
});

function ToggleHint(obj)
{
    if ($(obj).val() == '') { $(obj).addClass("hint"); };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the 'scroll' bit that you most likely copied from firebug is tripping up jQuery. It works otherwise when I tried your code. The other thing it could be is the path to the image.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">

    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <input type="text" id="edit-submitted-full-name" />

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
    $('#edit-submitted-full-name').focus(function(){

        $(this).css({background:'#FF00FF'});

     });

     $('#edit-submitted-full-name').blur(function(){
      if ($(this).val() == '') {
      $(this).css({background:'url(http://www.google.ae/images/srpr/nav_logo14.png) no-repeat 7px 5px #FFFFFF'});
      };
     });

    })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```